# What would be a good replacement for avidemux in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-conversion, avidemux

Apparently [avidemux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=avidemux) is not supported in Ubuntu beyond Trusty (14.04)
What would be a good replacement for it in later versions like 16.04 LTS or more recent?

I am actually looking for a program to convert raw digital video files to various formats: mp4, xvid, ogg, mp4 ... Preferably a (cli) program that I can use in a script.

Comment: What did you use `avidemux` for? A good replacement would be something that does the same things. What are those things?

Comment: This is possibly not a very good question.
I am actually looking for a program to convert raw digital video files to  various formats: mp4, xvid, ogg, mp4 ...
Preferably a (cli) program that I can use in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you were using Avidemux to do you might be able to get away with HandBrake for transcoding videos. There is also a command-line version of HandBrake named handbrake-cli. Otherwise install Kdendlive for working with raw video footage and other video editor functions. To install all three applications open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install handbrake-cli handbrake kdenlive
```